# Update con nomeros tipos float mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hola compañeros estoy tratando de hacer un **discount** mediante una consulta a la base de datos pero no logro conseguir lo que quiero.

aqui les explico que en mi base de datos hago una consulta que tiene que ir restando segun el usuario vaya haciendo click, la cosa es que en mi tabla tengo un campo tipo entero con un numero determinado **17** por ejemplo.

lo que nececito es que ese numero se le vaya restando **1.50** por cada consuta que haga el usuario eso equivale a 11 consultas en total, quiero decir que **17/1.50** serian 11 consultas para que el numero **17** llegue a cero.

lo he intentado cambiando ese campo a tipo **FLOAT** y **DOUBLE** pero no me funciona , aqui les dejo mi codigo

```
    $id=$_SESSION["user_id"];//user id
    $door_cost=1.50;//variable que obtiene el numero flotante

      $discount_my_coins=$con->prepare("UPDATE users SET ID_coins=ID_coins-? WHERE id=?");
      $discount_my_coins->bind_param("ii",$door_cost,$id);
      $discount_my_coins->execute();
```

> como resultado esto se va restando de uno en uno pero lo que yo quiero
>   es que el numero 17 llegue a cero en 11 clicks por ejemplo

alguna idea de que sucede aqui o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: creo pudieras crear un nuevo campo en tu base de datos que almacene la cantidad de intentos restantes según el costo asignado en tu variable `$door_cost` y de alli vas restando por cada consulta un -1 `SET  intentos_restantes = intentos_restantes - 1` y antes de tu script puedes crear una function que verifique si el campo `intentos_restantes > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aclarando que 17 puntos entre 1.50 que se le va a restar por cada click dado, no da 11 sino `11.33` que sería una cantidad con un número decimal periódico que es la parte del `.33333.....` por lo que no va a dar exactamente 0 en los clicks mencionados; dado eso deberás implementar una solución que muestre la cantidad cerrada a 2 o 0 decimales

Tu tipo de dato con el que esta almacenado el valor a decrementar no coincide con el valor que deseas restar, pues uno es de tipo `INT` y el otro de tipo `DECIMAL` por eso al momento de llevar a cabo el `UPDATE` solo le quita la unidad `1`

Lo primero que debes hacer es un `ALTER` de la tabla para después con un `MODIFY` alterar la estructura original de dicha columna, con algo como esto

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN ID_coins DECIMAL(4, 2);
```

Para que de este modo si por ejemplo tenías almacenado un valor de `17` ahora aparezca como `17.00` con lo que después ya puedes dejar tu consulta de este modo

```
UPDATE users SET ID_coins  = ID_coins - 1.50;
```

**Nota importante**

Por otro lado la columna `ID_coins` no quedará en 0 dando 11 clicks, pues eso equivale a un total restado de `16.50` entonces requerirías de un docéavo click mas donde restes `.50` para llegar al resultado esperado

Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae02cab39f00f97fe47857e7b1cd6e79) con algunas pruebas hechas en SQL

Comment: me resulto genial, gracias amigo!